# I could not access my php files through web browser in MAC

Tags: php, apache

I have my apache server running locally.

http://localhost/

Giving default index.html(It works!)

All files I placed in the follwoing folder.

**/usr/local/var/www/htdocs**

I have a hello.php file in the same location.

Its content is,

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

But when I try following link

```
http://localhost/hello.php
```

It gives, Not found error.

```
The requested URL /hello.php was not found on this server.
```

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself. After placing the file under /Library/webserver/documents, My php file can be accessed